# Advice on why my code has stopped working?

Tags: python, pandas

I've written some code that checks the value of three columns (Crash_Month, Crash_Day and Crash_Time) of a data frame (one row at a time) and depending on the value of each cell it will then print the corresponding value as defined by the code. However, I've come back to my code and none of the if/elif statements seem to be working and my code now prints out the unconverted values instead of the values' corresponding value. How can I fix this? What is the issue? Any help is appreciated and i'll insert the code below

```
#Compute day year function
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('road_accidents_data_clean.csv',delimiter=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#----------------------------------------------
#n is the row which you wish to convert
n = 0
#----------------------------------------------

ctime = datetime.datetime.strptime(c,'%H:%M:%S').time()

Season = data.loc[n,'Crash_Month']
DayWeek = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day']
TPDay = data.loc[n,'Crash_Time']

def compute_day_year(Season,DayWeek,TPDay):

    Season = data.loc[n,'Crash_Month']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(Season):
        if item >= 1 <= 2:
             Season[i] = 'Summer'

        elif item >= 3 <= 6:
             Season[i] = 'Autumn'

        elif item >= 6 <= 9:
             Season[i] = 'Winter'

        elif item >= 9 <= 11:
             Season[i] = 'Spring'

        elif item == 12:
             Season[i] = 'Summer'  

        if not item in range(1, 12):
                Season[i] = 'INVALID'
                DayWeek[i] = 'INVALID'
                TPDay[i] = 'INVALID'

    DayWeek = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(DayWeek):
        if item == 1:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Monday'

        elif item == 2:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Tuesday'

        elif item == 3:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Wednesday'

        elif item == 4:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Thursday' 

        elif item == 5:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Friday'  

        elif item == 6:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Saturday'

        elif item == 7:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Sunday' 

        if not item in range(1, 7):
                Season[i] = 'INVALID'
                DayWeek[i] = 'INVALID'
                TPDay[i] = 'INVALID'

    TPDay = data.loc[n,'Crash_Time']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(TPDay):
        if datetime.time(6,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(11,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Morning'

        elif datetime.time(12,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(17,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Afternoon'

        elif datetime.time(18,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(23,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Evening'

        elif datetime.time(0,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(5,59,0):
                TPDay[i] = 'Night'


print(Season, DayWeek, TPDay)
```

Comment: Where is the function called? If it's not called, it doesn't do anything, that's why the values are unconverted.

Comment: calling the function (typing compute_day_year) yields this result: <function __main__.compute_day_year(Season, DayWeek, TPDay)> what do i need to do to get it to return the converted values instead?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, all of these conditions are wrong:

```
if item >= 1 <= 2:
```

The above is equivalent to `item >= 1 and 1 <= 2`, which is just `item >= 1`. I believe that you really meant to write:

```
if 1 <= item <= 2:
```

... which translates to `item >= 1 and item <= 2`, and *that* is what you wanted to express.

Comment: Just more explanation: `item >= 1 <= 2` == `item >= 1 and 1 <= 2` == `item >= 1` (because 1<=2 is always true)

Comment: @h4z3 basically I just need to check if the value for each cell is between a range of x and y, what was the equivalent of what I was doing before? (just for future clarification)

Comment: @TaipanCodes it's in my answer, sorry, is not clear?

Comment: you're right- it's in your answer. My apologies, it is very late. I'm still trying to get this to work because changing the if statements hasn't changed the output, i'm just beginning coding so im not quite sure how to get the output (the converted figures) from this function.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues:

1. first thing pointed out by Óscar about the if's
2. the function doesn't return anything
3. the function is not called anywhere

3, from comments:

> calling the function (typing compute_day_year) yields this result:  what do i need to do to get it to return the converted values instead?

Calling = adding parentheses with parameters. ;)

2: There are two options:

- add `return Season, Dayweek, TPDay` at the end of the function (mind the indent - it should be in the function, but not the last for, so only one tab/group of 4 spaces); when calling the function, save the result
- or remove the parameter list (`def compute_day_year(Season,DayWeek,TPDay)` -> `def compute_day_year()`) and add `global Season, DayWeek, TPDay` as the first line of the function.

The first option is more preferred in general, but it seems you wanted to do the second one - you thought you are working on exactly the same objects.

BUT: You never use the original values of those parameters anyway, you always overwrite them. So the real fix is: **remove the variable declaration above the function, remove the parameter list, return the result**

1: Óscar already explained.

```
#Compute day year function
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('road_accidents_data_clean.csv',delimiter=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#----------------------------------------------
#n is the row which you wish to convert
n = 0
#----------------------------------------------

ctime = datetime.datetime.strptime(c,'%H:%M:%S').time()

#no declaration here

def compute_day_year(): # no parameter list here - you only use data object to get the desired values

    Season = data.loc[n,'Crash_Month']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(Season):
        if 1 <= item <= 2:  #fix 1
             Season[i] = 'Summer'

        elif 3 <= item <= 6:
             Season[i] = 'Autumn'

        elif 6 <= item <= 9:
             Season[i] = 'Winter'

        elif 9 <= item <= 11:
             Season[i] = 'Spring'

        elif item == 12:
             Season[i] = 'Summer'  

        if not item in range(1, 12):
                Season[i] = 'INVALID'
                DayWeek[i] = 'INVALID'
                TPDay[i] = 'INVALID'

    DayWeek = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(DayWeek):
        if item == 1:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Monday'

        elif item == 2:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Tuesday'

        elif item == 3:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Wednesday'

        elif item == 4:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Thursday' 

        elif item == 5:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Friday'  

        elif item == 6:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Saturday'

        elif item == 7:
             DayWeek[i] = 'Sunday' 

        if not item in range(1, 7):
                Season[i] = 'INVALID'
                DayWeek[i] = 'INVALID'
                TPDay[i] = 'INVALID'

    TPDay = data.loc[n,'Crash_Time']
    for (i, item) in enumerate(TPDay):
        if datetime.time(6,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(11,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Morning'

        elif datetime.time(12,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(17,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Afternoon'

        elif datetime.time(18,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(23,59,0):
                 TPDay[i] = 'Evening'

        elif datetime.time(0,0,0) <= ctime <= datetime.time(5,59,0):
                TPDay[i] = 'Night'
    return Season, DayWeek, TPDay

Season, DayWeek, TPDay = compute_day_year() 
print(Season, DayWeek, TPDay)
```

Comment: Okay right, that makes sense. It's returned a TypeError 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable on line:
----> 4     for (i, item) in enumerate(Season):
Also i really appreciate your help! thanks